# CoordinatorLayout + FrameLayout + ViewPager + RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout, android-framelayout

My App:

[image]
My root layout has bottom-navigation-bar and each item of `NavigationBar` corresponds to a `FrameLayout` that loads fragments with `ViewPager`s that also have several fragments with `RecyclerView`s.

I want to implement a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` inside my root layout and when a `RecyclerView` is scrolled within any `ViewPager`'s `Fragment`s, i want to collapse the collapsingtoolbar.

My problem is, I can implement this behavior when a `ViewPager` is child of `CoordinatorLayout` but not when a `FrameLayout` is child of a `CoordinatorLayout`. I need to implement `FrameLayout` otherwise i have to write toolbar code in each `BottomBar`'s item fragment's layout.

This is my root layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#4DBC76"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp">

                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="125dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:id="@+id/testRootFragment"
            >
        </FrameLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <bd.com.xbit.eat.bottom_navigation
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationViewTest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        app:elevation="25dp"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_selector"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my viewpager layout code that resides in a fragment which is called in the framelayout:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/talesTabLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/talesTabLayout"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
```

And this is my `RecyclerView` within a `Fragment`'s layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tales_all_recyclerView"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

I have used "`appbar_scrolling_view_behavior`" attribute in `Framelayout`, `ViewPager` and `RecyclerView` without any success. I have googled a lot but could not find any reference to this particular issue. Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"` for `CollapsingToolbarLayout` first to achieve the right behavior.

> I want to implement a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` inside my root layout
>   and when a `RecyclerView` is scrolled within any `ViewPager`'s `Fragment`s,
>   i want to collapse the `Toolbar`.

I didn't see any `Toolbar`s in your layout, however, i assume you used it inside `AppBarLayout` and this will help to achieve what you want:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

- Add the `Toolbar` in your root layout.

> My problem is, I can implement this behavior when a `ViewPager` is child
>   of `CoordinatorLayout` but not when a `FrameLayout` is child of a
>   `CoordinatorLayout`. I need to implement `FrameLayout` otherwise i have to
>   write `Toolbar` code in each `BottomBar`'s item `Fragment`'s layout.

Using `FrameLayout` in this situation (***In the `CoordinatorLayout`***) seems to be the best choice.

---

**However,** I'd do something else. Instead of adding `Fragment`s inside `Fragment` or whatever, I'd insert a `TabLayout` just under the `Toolbar` which contains multiple `Fragment`s just like this example of mine: https://github.com/LinX64/AndroidSupportDesign-TabLayout

This is how it should be designed. No need for views inside the each other, this will probably cause issues.

<sub>Nice design with those edges By the way.</sub>

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestion. My problem is my root layout has fragments that are initialized by the bottom bar, these fragments have viewpagers which also have fragments with recyclerview. Hence i am trying to use framelayout with scrollable behaviours in my root. Otherwise i would definitely follow your example.